# How to install and handle the event filter to Qt graphicsview

Tags: qt, events, event-handling, qt4, symbian

I have a `graphicsview` and a `graphicsscen`, but I don't know how to install and handle the event filter for getting the keyboard events. Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to handle the events for the whole view? For specific items? Please, give us more information.

Comment: ya for whole view i want to install the event filter.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created custom QGraphicsScene class you can just override QWidget's "QWidget::keyPressEvent()" and "QWidget::keyReleaseEvent()" methods.

```
class MyGraphicsScene : QGraphicsScene
{
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
}

//in cpp
void MyGraphicsScene::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    // do sth with event
}
```

If you are just using an istance of QGraphicsScene, you can use parent's keyPressEvent. Whether or not you must give more details

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do that:

1) Create your own class based on QGraphicsView and override keyPressEvent(). That only has sense if you going to change a lot of other things.

2) Install event filter, using installEventFilter(..) method and pass there filter object which will receive everything you might need